# Ignoring signer information in junit runner

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, spock

Some basic information, I currently work on an internal system which uses jars made by other teams within the company.

I'm currently adding some unit testing to our product, however I'm seeing problems when I'm mocking classes provided by the other teams. It appears that their jars are signed and when I try to mock I get these exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.example.MyClass$$FastClassByCGLIB$$730dfe4e"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:895)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)
```

Obviously this seems to make sense for security reasons. I'm just wondering if it's possible if the security check can be disabled within the junit runner/jvm, as most of our code depends on this third party code, and we can't just instantiate instances of these classes annoyingly.

I can confirm that if I remove the signature from the jars we are using, then the test passes.

It is not feasible to ask the other teams to not sign their jars, it's just as unfeasible for us to decompile all the jars we receive (usually 30 jars, once a week from a server install however it can be as many as four times a week). Our tests run on CI so we'd be having to use conditions (e.g. @IgnoreIf) to ignore the tests on CI which rely on these signed jars, reducing substantially the point of running CI.

Our development practices may not seem ideal, however due to the scale of the organisation. These will not be changing.

**Extra information**: we're using plain old Spock for unit tests with CGLIB to provide the mocking, sample test below. I see the above Exception when the jar is signed, and the test passes when the jar is not signed

```
def "My Test"() {

    given:
    def myClass= Mock(MyClass)

    when:
    def string = new String("hello")

    then:
    string == "hello"
}
```

Comment: This is the output of a unit test? Do you use a container for testing? Why don't you remove the signatures from the jars? If you really mock the classes then why there is this error?

Comment: Please post your code of your Spock test.

Comment: I've added more details in the question above, however I don't feel it adds anything to help solve this dilemma. The reason we get the Exception on the Mock, is because the Mock will not have the same signature as the class it's based on. So Java is doing what I would expect.

Comment: Apparently Jeremie B has found the solution after your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently fixed in cglib v3.2.1 with this commit : https://github.com/cglib/cglib/commit/f9d2f6cef31615d2dd98b3d41ca7de4b6294f2a0

It's linked to the issue [393](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/issues/393) for mockito and [SPR-12833](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12833) for Spring